# Implementing a diffusion equation (ions in sphere)...issue implementing nth roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, roots, matlab

Dear Matlab experts or mathematicians:

I am a biology student and need to correctly code a diffusion equation (equation 6.43) shown in the snapshot below from the Mathematics of Diffusion by Crank. My problem is in how to correctly calculate and implement the roots and use them inside equation 6.43 below. Here is what I have done (assuming that I only need to know the first root of B cotB + L-1 =0):

First: the roots of equation 6.41 were calculated:

```
F = @(z) 1 - z.*cot(z) - L;  % z is the root of the equation
z = linspace(0,3,1000);  
G=F(z);
plot(z,F(z),'k','linewidth',2);
hold on;
plot(z,0*z,'k');
% by inspecting the plot a value (K) close to zero can be obtained

root= fzero(@(z) 1 - z.*cot(z) - L, K); % note that fzero fails at large L  values ==> use fminbnd instead
end
```

now the first root is obtained which is by the way is ~ 3.14 since L > 1000.
Next, the equation 6.43 is solved as follows:

```
D= 1e-18 %cm/s
a = 2e-7 %cm
tmax = 1E8; % in sec  
t = linspace(0,tmax);
for  n=1:10:1000
zeta=(n*root)^2;    % I am not sure about if n*root is the correct implementation !!!
P=(zeta*(zeta + (L*(L-1))));
y=(6*L^2)*exp(-D*zeta*t/a^2)/P;
y=y+y;
w=1-y;
end
plot(t,w,'k','linewidth',2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEvC5.png)

The result I am getting is not right and I guess that the way I have implemented the nth roots in equation 6.41 is incorrect. My maths background is not great and so I suspect that my problem is in understanding the mathematical formula. I mainly do not understand why I need to know the other roots if I know the first root solution for equation 6.41??

Could you please help me out.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Both here and on places like Stack Overflow, it is usually good to reduce your problem to a minimal problem that would allow you to solve your full problem, rather than presenting your full problem. In this case the problem appears to be twofold: you have trouble getting a full set of numerical solutions to$1-z\cot(z)-L$ for widely variable $L$, and you're not sure why you even need more than one of them. The latter is easy to answer: equation (6.43) asks for all of them.

Comment: Thanks. Problem no one is now solved in matlab. A list of roots can be generated ...not sure how many are needed  but I can obtain say up to 250 roots.  Now the key problem is how to represent the list of roots mathematically for calculating the diffusion equation. By the way I've never seen a solution to this problem and hence my struggle!!!

Comment: Numerically, you can see the right side converges pretty quick as the roots get bigger, especially once $t$ has advanced to be a little bit positive. So in principle you can neglect the higher terms, though quantifying exactly how many you need to retain is nontrivial of course.

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointing that out.